# Subtracting Pandas columns caveat

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, warnings

There are many similar questions to this one, but I couldn't find the one that answers my questions specifically.

Firstly, when I run something like this

```py
df['new_col'] = df['col2'] - df['col1']
```

I get a warning saying "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead".

If I then try to run something like this

```py
df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df['col2'] - df['col1']
```

I get a "SettingWithCopyWarning" warning with the same message "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame. Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead".

Using the apply and lambda functions as suggested by some answers in other posts as raises a "SettingWithCopyWarning" warning and also seems to be a slow operation.

```py
df.loc[:, 'new_col'] = df.apply(lambda x: x['col2'] - x['col1'], axis=1)
```

I read the documentation pages, but I'm afraid I don't completely understand them, otherwise it would be clear to me what the correct format to make such calculation would be.

Right, so my question is: how do I subtract to columns of a Pandas dataframe to create a new for the same dataframe in the correct way so that Pandas is happy? Thank you!

Comment: the warning is because Pandas cant tell if the calculation is a view or a new array ( a view can change the data of the original dataframe). One way is to make an explicit copy, or use the ``assign`` method (internally it makes a copy; if you are creating multiple columns this is efficient, as the copy is made only once)

Comment: The problem is not `df['new_col'] = df['col2'] - df['col1']`. The problem is upstream of this operation. You have to publish your code before this line. A useful link: https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/

Answer (score 2):

Try adding `df = df.copy()`:

```
df = df.copy()
df['new_col'] = df['col2'] - df['col1']
```